# git ignore everything except files and folders under those folder matching a pattern

Tags: git, gitignore

I want git ignore to ignore everything except those files and folders which are subfolders of all folders matching a given name pattern.

example file structure:

```
 - .temp
 - stuff/
 - readme.txt
 - crap/pattern/more/stuff
 - crap/pattern/.temp
 - crap/pattern_test/
 - crap/more/pattern_test/
```

What I want to achieve is now something like:

```
/*
/*/
!.gitignore
!*/pattern*/*
```

So from the top example I would like git to not ignore:

```
 - crap/pattern/*
 - crap/pattern/more/*
 - crap/pattern/more/stuff/*
 - crap/pattern_test/*
 - crap/more/pattern_test/*
```

Is that possible? I tried a lot of patterns without any success:

```
!/pattern*/*
!/pattern*/
!*/pattern*/*
!*/pattern/*
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up your .gitignore file like this:

```
# Ignore everything by default
*
# Whitelist the .gitignore file
!.gitignore
# Whitelist folders at any level
!**/*/
# Whitelist every file under folders that match the pattern at any level
!/**/pattern*/**/*
```

Comment: @Mulgard My bad, i misunderstood you. Now it should whitelist(not ignore) the folders that either match pattern exactly or begin with it.

Comment: `!/pattern**/**/* ` does not make gitignore to include the correct folders. I guess because the parent folder `crap` is getting ignored, it does not even try to include some subfolder of `crap`

Comment: @Mulgard Changed it again. With these rules, it would include files under "crap" subfolders, but not in the crap folder itself.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was not clear enough so I added an additional example to my post. The folders matching the `pattern` could be at any level. So I dont know for sure if its under `crap/` it can also be under `crap/more` or under `stuff/`.

Comment: @Mulgard We're getting close. Do please try the last edit changes.